# How can I set up autocompletion for Git commands?

Tags: linux, git, bash, debian

I have Git (version 1.7.2.5) bash compeletion working on my Debian squeeze (6.0). Git was installed with aptitude and I am using standard debian's `bash`, which supports command line autocompletion.

Now, I just installed Git (1.5.6.5) on an other machine (Lenny/Debian 5.0) and the there is no autocompletion.

1. Why is Git autocomplete not working on the second machine? How do I diagnose this?
2. What is making completion work on my machine? I have looked for the file `git-completion.bash` but it doesn't seem to be on my machine. How does Git complete ever work?
3. How can I bring git complete to the other machine?

Comment: This *may* be more suitable question for either [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) or [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Please make sure that you compiled git with auto-completion if you compiled from source. Also make sure that you are using the same shell as on your old machine and that it supports auto-completion. As you can see, I'm not sure what is causing it so leaving it as a comment. It's probably either your shell not providing completion for it or git not installing completion properly. Good luck.

Comment: @poncha thanks. I will post again on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MateuszKowalczyk thanks. I installed git with aptitude. I'm using standard debian's bash which supports completion. Both machines have the same Debian version.

Comment: Do you have bash-completion installed? How about git-completion (although this should come in with git by default).

Good luck on stackexchange

Comment: Try `source /etc/bash_completion.d/git` it should enable it in the current shell. If it does, check your bash init scripts.

Comment: @Banthar Thanks this makes Autocomplete working.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1310317/why-does-debian-not-autocomplete-all-git-commands

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to `source /etc/bash_completion.d/git` to enable git auto-completion.

In my `.bashrc` it's done with:

```
for file in /etc/bash_completion.d/* ; do
    source "$file"
done
```

Comment: This did not work for me, since some of the completion scripts inside `/etc/bash_completion.d/` used helper functions defined in `bash_completion`.

Comment: This works for CentOS 7 as there is no `/etc/bash_completion` file.

Answer (score 64):

### For Debian Squeeze (6.x):

Put the following lines in your `~/.bashrc`

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

The script/program `/etc/bash_completion` already includes the scripts in `/etc/bash_completion.d` and also defines some functions needed by the included scripts.

---

### For Ubuntu Bionic and up (^18.04):

Put the following lines in your `~/.bashrc`

```
if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
fi
```

---

### For Fedora 20 & macOS High Sierra

See comments

Comment: In my Fedora 20 system `bash_completion` is located in `/usr/share/bash-completion/`. Running `updatedb && locate bash_completion` should help you find it.

Comment: This also solved my "no command 'have' found" issue.  The "have" function is defined in /etc/bash_completion, and many scripts in /etc/bash_completion.d/ depend on it.

Comment: i know it's not a mac question, but I'd note I don't think this file (`/etc/bash_completion`) exists high sierra. Also, my `bash_completion.d` is at `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d`. @Piotr's answer with the above directory the trick though.

Comment: **/etc/bash_completion.d** is a legacy directory, where bash completions were loaded **eagerly** to your shell, whereas 
**/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/** is a new location for completion files, and completion files in this directory loaded **on-demand**, i.e. only if they needed, [check doc](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/README.md#installation)

Comment: On Rasperry Pi OS (Debian-based), remember the bashrc file is located under /etc/bash.bashrc

Answer (score 43):

You need to install this package if missing. And then logout and login.

```
apt-get install bash-completion
```

Comment: after installation execute `source /etc/bash_completion`

Comment: worked on Arch Linux. I had to restart my terminals after the installation.

Comment: It also worked on Android Termux.

Comment: Works for distrobox emulation of Ubuntu 22.04 too!

Answer (score 15):

The shortest way to activate the bash auto-completion for Git on Debian is to add

```
source /etc/bash_completion.d/git
```

to the `~/.bashrc` (and restart the terminal).

See also here: "Pro Git" -> 2.7 Git Basics - Tips and Tricks -> [Auto-Completion](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks#Auto-Completion).

Answer (score 5):

Get the git autocompletion script:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -o ~/.git-completion.bash
```

Add to your .bash_profile in home directory:

```
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  . ~/.git-completion.bash
fi
```

Source your .bash_profile after this like:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 3):

For **Manjaro** and other Arch-based distros. I know it's about debian, but most things are the same but sometimes not. Whatever OS you use you'll end up here.

In your `~/.bashrc` add:

```
source /usr/share/git/completion/git-completion.bash
```

And then in terminal

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Finally a solution that works for Arch-based distros (which are becoming increasingly more popular these days). Cheers! \o

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu/Debian

Install Git and bash-completion by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install git bash-completion
```

I don't think you need to do anything else.

Comment: Make sure you try to autocomplete a common git command like "git clone" because it's just that SOME commands don't autocomplete like "git update-index"

Comment: Also works for some RPM-based distributions, with `yum install bash-completion`

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Ubuntu (observed on 20.04) seem to have split completions into multiple paths. For Ubuntu 20.04, I had to add the following to my `.bashrc` (taken from the default bashrc found in `/etc/bash.bashrc`):

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Notepad++ to edit your ~/.bashrc file. 
Put the line at the bottom of the script with a # at the beginning of the line. Save the file. For example:
 # source C:\cygwin64/etc/bash_completion.d/git

Don't forget to put the entire file path after 'source' and in front of '/etc/' For example, my cygwin64 folder which contains the 'etc' folder is in my c drive so my file path is c:\cygwin64/etc therefore the line I included in my bashrc file is:

```
# source c:\cygwin64/etc/bash_completion.d/git
```

Save bashrc file. Open Cygwin Terminal ... Boom! It's go time.
I then entered the following command and it worked.
`git clone git:\/\/github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper -b bleeding-jumbo JtR-Bleeding`

Comment: the question is about debian, not windows

Answer (score 0):

At times git auto-complete disappears because you accidentally deleted your ~/.bashrc file. Check if the bashrc file is there in your home directory. If not, you can always copy it from:

```
/etc/skel/.bashrc
```